# Copy from a specific cell up to the last cell that has data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy from a specific cell up to the last cell that has data
and paste it into a worksheet.

If I change

```
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
data = sheet.Range("A16" & Lastrow)
```

to

```
data = sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

it copies all the data cells on a file

Here is the full code:

```vb
Public Sub CopyRangeToArray(ByVal filename As String _
                        , ByVal sheetName As String _
                        , ByRef data As Variant)

    Dim book As Workbook
    Set book = Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = book.Worksheets(1)
    
    Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    data = sheet.Range("A16" & Lastrow)
    
    book.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub


Public Sub ArrayToRange(ByRef arr As Variant, rg As Range)
    rg.Resize(UBound(arr, 1) - LBound(arr, 1) + 1, UBound(arr, 2) - LBound(arr, 2) + 1) = arr
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim filename As Variant
    filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="All FIles (*.*),*.*", MultiSelect:=True)
    
    If IsArray(filename) = True Then
        
        ' Clear existing data
        Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents
        
        Dim file As Variant, data As Variant, rgDest As Range
        For Each file In filename
            
            ' Copy the range to an array
            Call CopyRangeToArray(file, "DATA", data)
                       
            ' Get the last row with data
            Set rgDest = Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            If rgDest.Value <> "" Then Set rgDest = rgDest.Offset(1)
            
            ' Write the array to the range
            Call ArrayToRange(data, rgDest)
        
        Next file
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Example: I want to copy A16 to the last cell that has data. I don't need  from A1 to A15.
[image]

Comment: You wrote : `data = sheet.Range("A").CurrentRegion` it works perfectly. As far as I know, currentregion need column and row to work. So maybe it's a typo, you mean is something like this `data = sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion`. Please CMIIW. And maybe you want to have a look in this link https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/current-region/ .

Comment: i mean a have a data where i only want to copy A16 to the last cell that have data if i use CurrentRegion it select all of the data including data i dont want to copy

Comment: Have you read the link I provide ? So you know when to use the currentregion ? Also, I wonder what does it mean in this code `sheet.Range("A16" & Lastrow)` because your LastRow is a row number. Assume the LastRow result is 20, `range("A16" & LastRow` ---> gives you cell A1620.

Comment: @karma Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    data = sheet.Range("A16" & Lastrow) my expectation it will copy the cell a16 up to the last cell that have value sorry im just new to this and sorry  for my bad english